# Function that removes unwanted character from string

Tags: c, string, function, replace

I need to make a function that takes a string and a character, the function needs to remove all the occurrences of the character in the string and returns the total number of characters removed. I have managed to modify the string as to be able to remove the unwanted character but I can't seem to be able to replace the old string with the new one. Thanks for any replies in advance.

This is what I've managed so far:

```
int clearstr(char *st,char u){
    int i,j=0,total=0,size=strlen(st);
    char *new_str=calloc(size,sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(st[i]!=u){
            new_str[j]=st[i];
            j++;}
        else total++;
    }
    new_str[j]='\0';
    printf("%s",new_str);

    //until here all is good ,new_str has the modified array that i want but i can't find a way to replace the string in st with the new string in new_str and send it back to the calling function (main),thanks for any help // 

    return total;
}
```

Comment: new_str[j]='\0';
         for(i=0;i<j;i++){
         st[i]=*(new_str+i);}
        st[i]='\0';
  free(new_str);  another way i found to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new string but you are not using it yet.  You can use a function like `memcpy` or `strcpy` to copy the contents. You also don't deallocate the memory of the `calloc` call; this creates a memory leak. Try something like:

```
...
new_str[j]='\0';
printf("%s",new_str);

strcpy(st, new_str); // Copy the contents of the new string to the original one
free(new_str); // Clear the memory of the allocation in this function, otherwise you get a memory leak

return total; 
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot that's what i was looking for  but i couldn't manage to make it work for the life of me :D